# Open file with its default program via python

Tags: python, pdf

I need to implement the user guide of my program and I was thinking on putting a button that opens the pdf, like if its double clicked on Windows Explorer.
But I've tried with `os.popen(myfile)` and `open(myfile)` and the interpreter open it in python, so I can print and it prints me the info of the object `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='userguide.pdf' mode='r' encoding'cp1252'` and what I need is to open it with its native application to avoid embed the pdf into the program.
Any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open it in the default application for that file type:
subprocess.Popen([file],shell=True)

Considering that you are implementing a user guide, you may want to open it in a web browser.

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(r'file://C:\path\to\file.pdf')

Comment: First, I only need to open the pdf, windows by default, if there isn't installed any pdf program, it open pdf via browser.
But I will be thinkin in how to implement via Windows Help script.
By the way, so much thanks!